# How to delete duplicate rows in mysql with condition?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, row

I have a table like this:

```
Id  email     Active
---------------------
1    aaa        1      
2    aaa        1      
3    aaa        0      
4    aaa        0
```

I want to delete duplicate row but if Active have 1/0 value keep 1 value and delete 0 value.

I tried this query

```
select *  FROM tbl_name WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM tbl_name GROUP BY email)
```

And I expected this result :

```
Id  email  Active
---------------------
1    aaa        1
```

OR

```
Id  email  Active
---------------------
2    aaa        1
```

but actually result was :

```
Id  email  Active
---------------------    
4    aaa        0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect Id 1 and not ID 2?

Comment: @Stu It doesn't matter if Id 1 or 2, what I want is that if the rows are duplicated , delete the row with active value  0 and keep the row with active value of 1, I will edit the question for more clearly, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON (t1.active < t2.active OR (t1.active = t2.active AND t1.id > t2.id)) AND (t1.email = t2.email);
```

Comment: I tried your query but it doesn't work when I insert new row with bbb value and active 1 it's delete it with other rows and keeps just the row with id 1, I edited the question with more clearly. thanks

Comment: @NexoCola Add the condition `ON .. AND t1.email = t2.email`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Got to simulate your problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67b0ed8/1

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id smallint auto_increment not null,
email varchar(12),
active smallint,
  primary key test(id));
  
 insert into test
 values(null, 'aaa@aaa',1),
       (null, 'aaa@aaa',1),
       (null, 'aaa@aaa',0),
       (null, 'aaa@aaa',0),
       (null, 'bbb@bbb',1),
       (null, 'bbb@bbb',0);
```

And splited to three parts

01 - I updated all your records to inactive

```
UPDATE test
SET active = 0 
where id in (select * 
               from (select id 
                     from test t
                     where t.active = 1 
                     and email in (SELECT   
                                   email
                                   FROM test
                                   GROUP BY email 
                                   having count(id) >=1)
                    )t);
```

02 - I identified witch records are the same and activate them.

```
UPDATE test
SET active = 1
WHERE id in (SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT max(id) from test 
   where active = 0
   group by email) t
);
```

03- I deleted the rest of inactive records

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE active = 0;
```

Let me know if it helped you